# How can I calculate on a column that I generate in the SELECT part of a query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I apologize for the horrible title, I really couldn't figure out how to explain what I'm trying to do in one sentence.

So I'm using laravel and a model trait called [searchable](https://github.com/nicolaslopezj/searchable) to help me create queries that search the varchar and text fields on my tables. So for example, that trait (after I modified it a bit) created the huge query you can see in this gist:

https://gist.github.com/Evertt/af025d741b802fc08af3

As you can see near the bottom of that query, it only selects records that have a relevance score that's higher than 8. Now here's my issue, I would like that number to be calculated live by MySQL. I don't know exactly how yet, but something like I only want to select records that have a relevance score in the top 80 percentile of all matched records... Something like that.

Now when I tried to change that line to `HAVING relevance > (MAX(relevance) / 2)` just as an experiment, it didn't work. It returned all matched records with a relevance score of more than 0, which probably means it didn't execute the `MAX()` function the way I wanted it to.

Can anybody give me some guidance on how I could make the `HAVING relevance = ...` follow a certain calculation based all relevance scores?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `MAX(relevance)`?

Comment: @lukasgeiter, you are correct. I did write it correctly when I tested the code, it was just a typo on here.

Answer (score 0):

i believe you cant use the calculated column name in the having clause, you have to use the full expression there.
Also, seems to me your group by will cause problems. If you want all (distinct) actors why not just group by actors.id ?